# what are PropertyChangeSupportand VetoableChangeSupport in basemodel in java

Tags: java

what is  `PropertyChangeSupport`
and
what is  `VetoableChangeSupport`
used in `Basemodel` in struts 2

Comment: PropertyChangeSupport -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html and VetoableChangeSupport -> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeSupport.html. I don't really know what you are asking here :S

Comment: [VetoableChangeSupport in JDK 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/VetoableChangeSupport.html) for an up-to-date version of the docs.

Comment: @DaveNewton:Any idea bout those classes i never saw not heard about them with respect to S2 and you are best person here to throw any light?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I don't know; I don't see them in any Struts 2 or XWork 2 code, but I only did a naive ack/grep. Nor is there anything called Basemodel, BaseModel, etc. AFAICT the OP is asking about something local to their app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform any action, when a property in a bean is changed, you use ChangeSupport.

You register the listeners and source (bean) whose property/properties are monitored for change.

VetoableChangeSupport is used for constrained properties, so you fire the VetoableChange (invoke the listener) before actually setting the new value for the property.

PropertyChangeSupport is used for bound properties, so you fire the PropertyChange after setting the new value for the property.

Please check the examples provided in the jdk.